# Change on.('click') to hover for keyboard accessible dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, dropdown

I'm modifying an existing dropdown menu that is WCAG compliant but need to change the functionality so that it works by hovering instead of clicking. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.has-submenu').each(function (i, event) {
    var $event = $(event);
    var name = $event.text();
    $event.addClass('open-menu')
      .attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
      .attr('aria-label', 'Open ' + name + ' menu');
  });

  $('.open-menu').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
      $target.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
      return;
    }
    var parentMenus = $target.parentsUntil('.nav-items').filter('ul').prev('a.open-menu');
    $('.nav-items a.open-menu[aria-expanded=true]').not(parentMenus).attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $target.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
  });
});
```

You can see the script working here: http://jsfiddle.net/58wtuc9x/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing...

```
$('.open-menu').on('click'
```

To...

```
$('.open-menu').on('click mouseenter'
```

This way it will execute if you click it, or if your mouse enters the element.  Or take off the click if you want just the hover effect.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar. This works but how can I add another function so that when the mouse leaves the dropdown, the menu automatically closes? See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dm3ao5kt/1/

Comment: @univers_ that would be a 'mouseleave' event handler that could close it.

Comment: If I attached the same function to mouseleave, then I have the same issue where I cannot move the mouse to the dropdown without it closing.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dm3ao5kt/5/

Comment: Ok, so without that handler, it works fine except when your mouse leaves the whole menu.  With it, it closes when you go to a sub menu.  So try attaching that mouseleave handler to the 'nav' element that encapsulates all the menu, and when that happens, just close whatever menu is open.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work but simplifying the code: http://jsfiddle.net/dm3ao5kt/23/ Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just attach a `hover` event handler as follows.

```
$('.open-menu').hover(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
      $target.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
      return;
    }
    var parentMenus = $target.parentsUntil('.nav-items').filter('ul').prev('a.open-menu');
    $('.nav-items a.open-menu[aria-expanded=true]').not(parentMenus).attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $target.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
  });
```

Comment: I did try this but then you cannot move the mouse to the dropdown menu once it's opened. See for yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/5cnsov2d/1/